# iOS 9 or later,first open other app will show a alert and i can not find the cancel action callback

Tags: ios, openurl

In iOS 9 or later my app first open another app, it'll tell me 'xx wants to open xx'.when i click cancel i cannot find where is the action call back.
who can help me.

Comment: What.. The signature on iOS 10+ is `func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any], completionHandler completion: (Bool) -> Void)` which has a completion block.. if the system fails to open the app/url, the completion block is called with `false`..  on iOS 9, it is `func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool` and it's synchronous. It will `return false` on failure..

Comment: but i used other sdk, i did not use openURL or other openURL related method